# script ends despite unresolved promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

Consider this:

```js
(async function () {
  const arr = [];
  await new Promise(r => arr.push(r));
  console.log("done")
})();
```

The scripts terminates at the `await` and the log is never printed to sdout, I don't understand why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code. That's just the model of Node. If there is no pending I/O pending promises don't prevent Node from exiting.

You can schedule some I/O if you want to stop Node from exiting but pending promises don't actually prevent Node from exiting.

I'm not saying I agree or like the behavior but that's what we currently do

Edit: found [the bug report/discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25504) in the issue tracker.

Comment: I am also not sure what the right thing to do here is (which is why I didn't comment in that issue) and I see both sides (no I/O and callback like behavior - and the process exiting surprisingly) as valid. If you feel strongly please weigh in on the issue. A surprising amount of these behaviors in Node is Node not being sure what the right behavior is.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I understand why node exits, but I still don't have an explanation on why I don't get the log printed to sdout

Comment: @NicoAdrian well, simply because that piece of code is never executed. Both because you are never actually fulfilling that promise (so even if node waited it wouldn't get executed) and even if you did - Node wouldn't wait the microtick promises wait to react to it. Try running the code with a setInterval in the background (so node doesn't exit)

Comment: I knew it worked with a setInterval but I expected it to at least execute the `console.log` but now I understand that, tell me if I'm wrong, when using async/await, the next line act as a callback or the `then` part of the promise

Comment: Yes, that's the gist. The whole point of async/await is that we get to write asynchronous code "as if" it is synchronous and the next line is "like a then" + error handling. As a fun this sort of abstraction of the core of "chain and return" is super fundamental to programming and is typically called "monadic", the functional equivalent for async/await from languages like Haskell is called "do notation" which allows for a lower-level chaining (for all sorts of stuff not just I/O).

Comment: And if you hear people happy about those things (do notation in Haskell, async/await in JS/C#/Rust/whatever or to an extent try in scala) they are really excited and happy about the same thing. The ability to tame the notion of chaining things and to control it in a non-linear fashion so application code controls when the next line executed. In JS this is also possible with (more flexible but worse tooling) coroutines (and yield).

Comment: Ok. I used to write a lot of async/await code but with python and its behaviour is quite different from JS, that's why I was confused. Thanks for you explanations

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think exiting (cleanly) is definitely the right behaviour for node. If it didn't, it would just hang - if there are no pending events and no ongoing IO, then no other code will ever run, the program would do nothing - forever. As you said, there's nothing around that might settle the promise and run its handlers, so there's no reason to keep it around.